# Search text in particular column and retrieve data from another column in excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, search, ini

I have an Excel file of 20 columns and there are about 150 records. I need to search for a particular string in a particular column with header "DESCRIPTION"(usually column b). The search string and column header values come from an INI File. After the search is found, I need to copy the value in column J (again from INI file) to the output file.

I am new to C#. Can somebody help me here. I tried Range.Find but I got confused.

Comment: You should first post some code you've done, and you will get help with it. Why are you using C#, especially if you are new to it ? There are other languages, easier to learn, that allow you to manipulate Excel data

Answer (score 0):

Usually OLEDB with SQL like statements can be used to retrieve specific column or row data. Please go throgh following solutions:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6b8651/read-excel-file-in-windows-application-using-C-Sharp/

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1088970/read-write-excel-file-with-oledb-in-csharp-without

Hope this will give you some idea. But try to show some of your code so that members can have the better understanding of your approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Oledb connection you can also use ClosedXML. ClosedXML is a wrapper around OpenXML that allows you to easily work with .XLSX files.

https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML.

You can look at the documentation that'll help you understand how to search for text.

If you want to search .XLS files, then you can use the Microsoft Excel Interoperability libraries. These libraries cannot be used in a web app, are slower than ClosedXML but they support all kinds of Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free version of [GemBox.Spreadsheet](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet) to search for a text in both XLS and XLSX file formats. Also regarding the INI file, you can use [MadMilkman.Ini](https://github.com/MarioZ/MadMilkman.Ini).

Here is an example that you could try:

```
// Load INI file.
IniFile ini = new IniFile();
ini.Load("Sample.ini");

// Get INI values.
string header = ini.Sections["SampleSection"].Keys["ColumnHeaderValue"].Value;
string search = ini.Sections["SampleSection"].Keys["SearchTextValue"].Value;
string j = ini.Sections["SampleSection"].Keys["JColumnValue"].Value;

// Load XLSX file.
ExcelFile excel = ExcelFile.Load("Sample.xlsx");
ExcelWorksheet sheet = excel.Worksheets[0];

// Find column header value in first row.
ExcelColumn searchColumn = sheet.Rows[0].Cells
    .First(cell => cell.ValueType == CellValueType.String && cell.StringValue == header)
    .Column;

// Find search value in column.
int r, c;
searchColumn.Cells.FindText(search, false, false, out r, out c);
ExcelCell searchCell = sheet.Cells[r, c];

// Get cell from column "J" that is in the same row as cell that has search text.
ExcelCell jCell = sheet.Cells[r, ExcelColumnCollection.ColumnNameToIndex("J")];
// Set cell value.
jCell.Value = j;

// Save XLSX file.
excel.Save("Sample.xlsx");
```